# How can this link (and links in general) run javascript through a Google link?

Tags: web-application, http

Very recently, the following link has come to my attention:

```
hxxps://google.co.zm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=Cm6zn8V32DYq0XBaSUlxVBIIAuEiVXBuKemW-4NV&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.zm%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26cad%3Drja%26uact%3D8%26ved%3DmhszSJlZLNv5WQ7t2uAcnUY-YTM29XBFvT7UpjgZ%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.cv%252Furl%253Fsa%253Dt%2526rct%253Dj%2526q%253D%2526esrc%253Ds%2526source%253Dweb%2526cd%253D1%2526cad%253Drja%2526uact%253D8%2526ved%253DEV2aCWOtJ--La2FQgCv5zZhUu5dHiEfZRaMhmRwC%2526url%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.google.dz%25252Furl%25253Fsa%25253Dt%252526rct%25253Dj%252526q%25253D%252526esrc%25253Ds%252526source%25253Dweb%252526cd%25253D1%252526cad%25253Drja%252526uact%25253D8%252526ved%25253Dn-n1rTUOTdombswN7m8XCZtoKS-3q7L8YpAdksb9%252526url%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fwww.google.bj%2525252Furl%2525253Fsa%2525253Dt%25252526rct%2525253Dj%25252526q%2525253D%25252526esrc%2525253Ds%25252526source%2525253Dweb%25252526cd%2525253D1%25252526cad%2525253Drja%25252526uact%2525253D8%25252526ved%2525253D89E6-ZBTfnewX62nn0_kmdhlJqbDevj9UXEKeQ8p%25252526url%2525253Dhttps%252525253A%252525252F%252525252Ftranslate.google.com.eg%252525252Ftranslate%252525253Fsl%252525253Den%2525252526tl%252525253Des%2525252526js%252525253Dy%2525252526prev%252525253D%2525252526hl%252525253Des%2525252526ie%252525253DUTF-8%2525252526u%252525253Dhttp%25252525253A%25252525252F%25252525252Fsmarturl.it%25252525252F2cr8dk%2525252526ta1d6obanmxpiuhsg5ey%25252526usg%2525253DpO6M7OfpakJr4HqI-O3HQaBSwu9UQaEA-7%25252526sig2%2525253DDFAA3d8Ya65HolUvW_dt87TLlv4S4AHDRm%25252526bvm%2525253Dbv.1524151093492%2525252Cd.eWE%252526usg%25253D9-q_3wUkmdHK7PImte1GPXJrJqp22mTEZr%252526sig2%25253DBDlEPpVvJeTCswD1IMDwP1hUBmzKW22v7O%252526bvm%25253Dbv.1524151093492%25252Cd.eWE%2526usg%253DHIjzPu8E4AwRrlhGGEbPcRC9wGMTFd-dmZ%2526sig2%253Djsb05c8cOGjscucG9seVGmgy9ITemV4yyh%2526bvm%253Dbv.1524151093493%252Cd.eWE%26usg%3D8haBtM2jBo3-W8ak0UFjJsUJNdAEYxMAkc%26sig2%3Dz0b8k27Xb7xCgWZk4EUm9wcHkPnatxK8j3%26bvm%3Dbv.1524151093493%2Cd.eWE&usg=E4RSEupGwJUc5oO1GLQVHOzPYvVp34jxOD&sig2=2D4fRTTiml2TuRGSjqXk5c4Ryk9ps0es2d&bvm=bv.1524151093493,d.eWE?lkgfhgh6k4j6dskjfuetipgfbg5tg/rt54t09657gh/bkfv//,.52.4
```

***Note** that discretion is advised with opening this link as it may be harmful*

It is a link shared over Facebook (pretending to be a link on YouTube) by a friend and its comments have a tremendous amount of people tagged on this post by the friend.

Upon running it with TorBrowser, it does several redirections to the Google page of different nationalities until ending with a spanish Google Translate page with a `smarturl.it` link that leads to `youtube.com`.

I am assuming that in the process it automatically uses the open facebook tab of a user to make such post again, tagging all the friends the person has.

Has anything like this ever been encountered before? Is this some typical mechanism that spammers use?

---

If not then what does closer inspection of this link show?

Answer (score 1):

If you URL decode it a few times, it's not Javascript:

```
https://google.co.zm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=Cm6zn8V32DYq0XBaSUlxVBIIAuEiVXBuKemW-4NV&url=
http://www.google.co.zm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=mhszSJlZLNv5WQ7t2uAcnUY-YTM29XBFvT7UpjgZ&url=
http://www.google.cv/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=EV2aCWOtJ--La2FQgCv5zZhUu5dHiEfZRaMhmRwC&url=
http://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=n-n1rTUOTdombswN7m8XCZtoKS-3q7L8YpAdksb9&url=
http://www.google.bj/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=89E6-ZBTfnewX62nn0_kmdhlJqbDevj9UXEKeQ8p&url=
https://translate.google.com.eg/translate?sl=en&tl=es&js=y&prev=&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=
http://smarturl.it/2cr8dk&ta1d6obanmxpiuhsg5ey&
usg=pO6M7OfpakJr4HqI-O3HQaBSwu9UQaEA-7&
sig2=DFAA3d8Ya65HolUvW_dt87TLlv4S4AHDRm&
bvm=bv.1524151093492,d.eWE&
usg=9-q_3wUkmdHK7PImte1GPXJrJqp22mTEZr&
sig2=BDlEPpVvJeTCswD1IMDwP1hUBmzKW22v7O&
bvm=bv.1524151093492,d.eWE&
usg=HIjzPu8E4AwRrlhGGEbPcRC9wGMTFd-dmZ&
sig2=jsb05c8cOGjscucG9seVGmgy9ITemV4yyh&
bvm=bv.1524151093493,d.eWE&
usg=8haBtM2jBo3-W8ak0UFjJsUJNdAEYxMAkc&
sig2=z0b8k27Xb7xCgWZk4EUm9wcHkPnatxK8j3&
bvm=bv.1524151093493,d.eWE&
usg=E4RSEupGwJUc5oO1GLQVHOzPYvVp34jxOD&
sig2=2D4fRTTiml2TuRGSjqXk5c4Ryk9ps0es2d&
bvm=bv.1524151093493,d.eWE?
lkgfhgh6k4j6dskjfuetipgfbg5tg/rt54t09657gh/bkfv//,.52.4
```

It's just chaining calls to Google, then Google Translate, then to smarturl.com with a lot of arguments added.

The URL `http://smarturl.it/2cr8dk` goes to Youtube.

Comment: Any clues as to what those arguments could be? It seems as if this link can make posts automatically

Comment: that's entirely up to smarturl